# Create and call custom function name in loop with self argument

Tags: python-3.x, function, self

So I am working on a PYQT5 project and I have several textLabels which I want to populate from JSON file
They are named  `labelType1`, `labelType2`, `labelType[n]`

When I want to setText to this labels from my `MainWindow` how can I construct function name for the function `self.labelType1.setText("...")` . So like this

```
for x in range(100)

     self.labelType[x].setText("name"+str(x))
```

I cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <object>.__getattribute__(<string name>)(<params>)
```

this is the answer